# related UI not update in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array in my data object and it will `push` as many time user wants to add data to it, and it is rendering with `v-for` perfectly.

The problem is related UI part didn't update, see the following picture :

this is init of the page and there is an empty object in array

[image: init image]

when I press `add` button `panel-body` would not update with new `v-for` generated elements:

[image: after add data picture link]

thanks

EDIT:

When I write the code in pure pure html(copy it in code), it look like this, that is a target UI.

[image: pictrure link]

EDIT 2:

data :

```
  data() {
    return {
      payment: {
        type: "check",
        checks: [{}]
      }
    }
  }
```

ui :

```
<div v-for="(check,index) in payment.checks">
  <br>
  <h5>
    index of array ->
    {{index}}
  </h5>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
     something
    <label style="color:red">*</label>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="check.amount" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">
     someting else
    <label style="color:red">*</label>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="check.dadada" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-8" style="padding-top: 3%;">
    <button v-on:click="payment.checks.push({})" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right: 7%;">
    add
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to see the code. Can you debug if the data array is being pushed at

Comment: @samayo data is push correctly, problem is in UI, but if it can help I put the code.

Comment: Yeah, it would be good to see how you are using v-for on your ui

Comment: @samayo updated with code.

Comment: it's working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/eb1pm55L/1/ maybe it was your typo

Comment: it works for me too, but the problem is UI, see the difference of pictures please.

Comment: position of `next` button should go down, but don't change with `v-for` but with static HTML it under elements.

Comment: if you want the Next button to appear always after the last box, then add that button in your example.

Comment: seems like a css issue